# Browser resize as a function listener to animate other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

So, I've got a function animateSection() that animates two elements, #awards and #twitter.

I want to make it so that if a user resizes the browser

```
function animateSection() {
  var $checker  = $(window).width(),
      $twitter  = $('#jstwitter'),
      $awards   = $('#awards');

  var distance = 20,
      duration = 500;

  if($checker > 1140) {
    $twitter.fadeIn(duration, function() {
      $awards.fadeIn(duration);
    });
  } 
  else {
    $(window).resize(function(){
      // here is where I run into trouble...
      if($checker > 1140) {
        $twitter.animate({left: distance}, duration);
        $awards.animate({right: distance}, duration);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're first run the function you're storing `$(window).width()` in a local variable, `$checker`, then on resize you're checking that variable. It's not going to change! Try replacing:

```
if ($checker > 1140) {
```

with:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1140) {
```